Is it possible to quote a message using the chat-api?
I'm trying to import some data to google chat using the chat API, but searching in the documentation i could'nt find a way to create a message quoting a previous message in the chat. Accordingly to the API, the Message resource has an attribute called "quotedMessageMetadata" but this is an output only property, and the method used to create message doesn't accept any argument indicating the message quoting.
Is this possible ?
A reference to the documentation or an api call that can achieve message quoting in the google chat api

Welcome to StackOverflow.  In order to get help. your question must contain the code you tried in text format, and any results or errors as well.  People can not edit a picture, so post code so someone can adjust it for you.  Good luck.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Quoting messages is a relatively new feature and is not yet available via the API.
However, there is a feature request for this capability. You can upvote it to get Google's attention:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/318404231

I see, thank you for the response, i'll upvote it.

@GuilhermeCarlosRodriguesde Since you don't have enough reputation to upvote, please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark button to the left of my response if it addresses your question. Thanks.
